# Can't extend Num with a custom operator overload to achieve the commutative rule

Tags: dart, extension-methods

I have class `Amount` which I added the multiplier operator which works fine( `amount * 3`). To achieve the behavior (`3* amount`) I added an extension method to the type `num`.

```dart
/// file path: src/domain/entities/amount/amount.dart
class Amount {
  final double amount;
  final String unit;
  Amount({
    @required this.amount,
    @required String unit,
  });
...
 Amount operator *(num multiplier) => copyWith(amount: amount * multiplier);
...
}

extension NumAmountExtension<T extends num> on T {
  Amount operator *(Amount amount) => amount * this;
  Amount multiply(Amount amount) => amount * this;
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't the trick.

```dart
/// file path: test/domain/entities/amount_tests.dart
final amount = Amount(amount: 3, unit: 'kg')
final newAmount = amount * 3;
final newerAmount = 3.multiply(amount) // this works fine
final otherNewAmount = 3 * amount //error: The argument type 'Amount' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [core] test/domain/entities/amount_tests.dart:83)
```

I do not understand why the `multiple`-extension works an the `operator *` doesn't. As far I extension method understand that should be possible.

Comment: I believe the error is from method resolution. Since `num` already has an `*` it resolves to num's `*` method. That aligns with the error given as num's `*` has parameter type of `num` and `Amount` can't be assigned to `num`. A workaround is: `NumAmountExtension(3) * amount` and that resolves how you'd expect. That said, the error message is misleading.

Comment: Thx @hola, that was it. 